# GoにおけるDatastoreクエリのFilter(不等式)とDistinctOnを同時に使う方法

Tags: sql, go, database, google-app-engine

抽出したいEntityはStatusがdone、AgentIDがagentID(変数)
UserIDがユニークでありTagが learn < Tag < mathを満たすようなもの。
※ UserIDをユニークなものにする為にCreatedAtでOrderして一番初めのものを取得すればいいと考えています。

そのため以下のようなクエリを作成したい。

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Task").
    Filter("Status =", "done").
    Filter("AgentID =", agentID).
    Filter("Tag >", "learn").
    Filter("Tag <", "math").
    DistinctOn("UserID")
```

しかしエラーは起きないもののDistinctOnが動作しないので

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Task").
    Filter("Status =", "done").
    Filter("AgentID =", agentID).
    Project("UserID", "Tag").
    DistinctOn("UserID").
    Filter("Tag >", "learn").
    Filter("Tag <", "math")
```

のようにProjectを使用してからではないとDistinctOnが動作しない。
しかしこのようにしてしまうとTagをDistinctOnに入れろとエラーが起きるので期待通りのクエリを作成することができない。(DistinctOn("UserID", "Tag")とすればエラーは消えるがUserIDが
ユニークにならなくなる)

考えられる解決策としては
・ Projectを使わずにDistinctOnを使えるようにする。
・ Filter（不等式）を使ってもProject、DistinctOnに入れなくてよいようにする。

datastoreでこのようなCountをする操作はナンセンスだとは承知の上ですが、
もし解決例があれば教えて頂きたいです...。

GCP Datastoreドキュメント
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries?hl=ja#datastore-datastore-distinct-on-query-go

Comment: 確認ですが、`Tag` カラムの値だけが異なるレコードが複数存在するのでしょうか？

Comment: そうなりますと、`UserID` だけでは distinct はできません。。。エラーメッセージ「TagをDistinctOnに入れろ」の通りにするか、DistinctOn を外したクエリの結果を受け取って自分で加工するなどの対応が考えられます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
`DistinctOn("UserID", "Tag")`のようにしてしまうとTagまでユニークなものにしてしまうのでTagは`math<Tag<learn`を満たしかつUserIDのみユニークなものでフィルタリングはできないでしょうか？

Comment: ええと、Tag までユニークなものにしてしまうことはありません。あくまで、UserID と Tag の組み合わせが一意になるという事です。例えば、UserID が 100 で Tag が A というレコードと、UserID が 100 で Tag が B というレコードがあれば、DistinctOn("UserID", "Tag") で両方とも抽出されます。

Comment: なるほど...! そういうことでしたか。。。今回の場合どうしてもUserIDはユニークなもの(同じものは抽出しない)にしたいのでUserID が 100 で Tag が A というレコードと、UserID が 100 で Tag が B というレコードがあった時初めの一つだけ抽出するというのは可能でしょうか？

Comment: その「初めの一つ」が具体的にどのような条件で決まるのか？によります。おそらくですが、他の RDB と同様に Datastore でもレコードの登録順序で抽出されるとは限らないと思われます。

Comment: Filterを使用した上で他のカラム値がユニークなものを抽出するという操作はdatastoreでも可能なんですね...! 「初めの一つ」はCreatedAtでOrderして
一番初めのもので取得すればいいと考えています。

Comment: 「「初めの一つ」はCreatedAtでOrderして一番初めのもので取得すればいいと考えています。」の部分を質問文に追記していただけますか？